# Iphone Error "request for member connectWeb in something not a structure or union"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

When I call my urlconnection method from my (IBAction)buttonpressed method like this:

[self connectWeb];

I get error "request for member connectWeb in something not a structure or union"

but when I call the same method from my - (void)viewDidLoad method it works!?

Comment: try adding 'connectWeb' method to the header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the `connectWeb` method in your implementation file?

I would guess that it is before `viewDidLoad` but after `buttonPressed`.

The reason for this is that the `connectWeb` method has been declared before `viewDidLoad`, so `viewDidLoad` is aware of it, whereas it's after the `buttonPressed` method, so the `buttonPressed` method isn't aware of it.

You have a couple of options.

1. Declare the method before any other method uses it.

`- (void)connectWeb;`

Then you can implement it anywhere within the implementation.

1. Move the implementation of `connectWeb` to before both `viewDidLoad` and `buttonPressed` - both the methods will then be aware of `connectWeb`.

Comment: I didnt know order was important in Obj-C! thats strange

Comment: It's not so strange in compiled languages. When the compiler is compiling the buttonPressed method it isn't aware of connectWeb as it hasn't been 'told' about it yet. Forward declare or implement connectWeb before buttonPressed and then the compiler is aware that the method exists.

Answer (score 0):

A method missing from the header wouldn't cause this problem. Because Objective-C is dynamic, it will check if the instance implements that method at runtime, so as long as the method exists it will work. You would just get a compiler warning at build time.

Try deleting the line [self connectWeb] from your button delegate method and copy/pasting it from your viewDidLoad (or retyping it). From the error you're getting, it sounds like there might be an extra character in your statement. This happens to me from time to time, because I use synergy to share my keyboard & mouse between multiple computers.